# Could not load app or assembly - binding redirect not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, json.net, nuget

I have 2 nuget packages installed in my project one of which references Newtonsoft.json assembly v 7.0.0.0, and the other one - v 11.0.0.0

Because I cannot have 2 assemblies with different versions in a project I am referencing only the latest version and I am getting the following error: **Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

I tried doing a binding redirect in the App.config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but it seemingly has no effect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: where do you place the `App.config` while? it should be in the running app folder (containing the main module)

Comment: I'm working on a module to an existing system (i.e. I only have partial access to the code) so I'm essentially launching the application with Start External Program -> UI.exe Thank you for the suggestion though, it's some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest trying to reinstall the nuget package.
Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager and choose Package Manager Console, and use the following commands:

1.Remove all Newtonsoft.Json packs from the solution:

```
uninstall-package newtonsoft.json -force
```

2.Reinstall Newtonsoft.Json:

```
install-package newtonsoft.json
```

Then rebuild your solution.